# VBA Excel replace line breaks in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I would need to replace the line breaks in a cell, with a line break and the content of a cell in the same column of the active cell.

The code would be something like this:

```
 For i = LBound(arColumns) To UBound(arColumns)
   'ActiveColumn = arColumns(i)
   Set rng = Range(arColumns(i))

   For Each Cell In rng.Cells
     If Cell.row > 4 And Cell.row < r Then
       colnum=cell.column
       Cell.value = "{Something}" & Cells(3, colnum).value & _
           ", text here{/something}" & Cell.value  'First line in the cell
       cell.replace what:=vbCrLf, replacement:=vbCrLf & "{Something}" & _
           Cells(3, colnum).value & ", text here{/something}" 'First try
       Cell.value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(CStr(Cell.value), vbCrLf, vbCrLf & _
           "{maxlen}{/maxlen}{notes}" & ", No Max length{/notes}")  'Second try
     End If
   Next
 Next
```

I've tried to replace the values of the line breaks with the two methods, replace and substitute. None of them have been working or I am doing something wrong with this block of code.

The array arColumns have the range of columns that I want to work, for example: B:C,E:E,M:O,Z:AB...

Comment: Usually Line breaks in cells are not vbCrLf but vbLf (line feed) only.

Comment: I would not use the Cell.replace function but do it in pure VBA: `Replace(oldValue, vbCrLf, replace)`

This also facilitates a later refactoring to improve the execution speed significantly.

Comment: I don't know why I did not think of the replace. Thank you.
Also, thank you for the recommendation Vincent, I've changed it for vbLf and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

along with the `vbLf` fix you've already been told, you could refactor your code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim arColumns As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim r As Long, i As Long

    arColumns = Array("B:C", "E:E", "M:O", "Z:AB")
    r = 10 '<--| just to have a value to test with
    For i = LBound(arColumns) To UBound(arColumns)
        For Each cell In Intersect(Range(arColumns(i)), Rows("4:" & r)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through current columnns group not empty cells from row 4 to 'r'
            cell.Replace what:=vbLf, replacement:=vbLf & "{Something}" & Cells(3, cell.Column).Value & ", text here{/something}" 'First try
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```